# How to return List<int> from domain service

Tags: silverlight, wcf, wcf-ria-services, domainservices

Hello guys im using WCF RIA Services i have domain services where i wrote this method

```
public List<int> GetActionIDs() 
    {
        return (from d in ObjectContext.actions select d.id).ToList();
    }
```

How i can get this List in client side?
This does not works :

```
List<int> = db.GetActionIDs();
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Do you get any errors?  Do other methods of your web service work?  BTW, `List<int> = db.GetActionIDs();` is not valid - you need a variable name.

Comment: yes works and its gives this error:>> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: What line do you get that error on?

Comment: List<int> = db.GetActionIDs(); << on this line. if returning type is table everything works great

Comment: Try: `List<int> ids = db.GetActionIDs();`

Comment: loolz . i missted to write here that. Sure i wrote in my code List<int> ids = db.GetActionIDs(); like this.

Comment: I'm not too sure about Silverlight then.  Does `List<>` work otherwise in Silverlight?  Can you use an array instead?

Comment: @MikeChristensen No, Lists are absolutely OK in Silverlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should read the [RIA Services manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee707370%28v=VS.91%29.aspx), because you don't realize that service calls in Silverlight are asynchronous.

In your case, you should

Add `InvokeAttribute` to your operation in the service:

```
[Invoke]
public List<int> GetActionIDs() 
{
    return (from d in ObjectContext.actions select d.id).ToList();
}
```

Then, all calls to `DomainContext` are asynchronous, so you get your results in the callback:

```
db.GetActionIDs(operation =>
                {
                  //TODO: check the operation object for errors or cancellation

                  var ids = operation.Value; // here's your value

                  //TODO: add the code that performs further actions
                }
                , null);
```

Answer (score 0):

inside DomainSrvice

```
[Query]    
public List<Action> GetActionIDs()     
 {         
   List<Action> result =  (  
                           from a in ObjectContext.actions                                     
                            select new action                                   
                             {                        
                                ID = a.ID
                             }
                        ).ToList(); 
   return result ;
 }
```

Silverlight

```
DomainService1 DS = new  DomainService1();
LoadOperation<Action> LoadOp = Ds.Load(Ds.GetActionIDsQuery());

LoadOperation.Completed += new EventHandler((s,e)=>{
   foreach (Action item in LoadOp.Entities)
   {
   }
});
```